# Which county boundaries does Excel Power Map support?

Tags: excel, united-kingdom, microsoft-power-map-excel

I've got a bunch of UK data that is already aggregated to "county" level, that would merrily work in Mappoint 2006, however the borders it seems to use appear to be "odd", and some places just don't seem to be recognised.

[image: Screenshot]

What I don't understand is that we appear to have a boundary for the West Midlands (which it's matched against Walsall), but not Avon (which fell out of existence at the same time as the West Midlands). Lincolnshire appears to have merged the portions that were in Humberside, Rutland has popped into existence, and most of South Wales doesn't match up.

If there a way of influencing which sets of county borders to use, a way of making it only use borders that are in use at the same time, on the same map, or at least a list of the supported county names?

Comment: I have no experience with Excel Power Map, but at a first glance, i would say, you have a problem projecting your data. It seems like the geometries have been shifted southwards. Do you know the coordinate system of your base data (where is it from), and is it possible to edit the projection / transformation in Power Map?

Comment: Those are the boundaries that Power Maps has chosen - it seems odd that some of the boundaries are not contemporary with some of the others